# Proof of quotient set is a partition

Tags: elementary-set-theory

To prove a quotient set S/R is a partition of S, one of the requirements is that Union of S/R = S

This is a proof that i dont quite understand (proving S is a subset of S/R)
∀x∈S:x∈[x]
=>¬(∃x∈S:x∉[x])
=>¬(∃x∈S:x∉⋃[x])
=>∀x∈S:x∈⋃S/R
=>S⊆⋃S/R

Why can't we skip the De Morgan's Law steps and straightaway conclude that x∈⋃S/R?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can. For any $x\in S$ you manage to  exhibit an element $c\in S/R$ with $x\in c$ (namely you can pick $c=[x]$), hence $x\in\bigcup S/R$.